# Autowiring multiple repositories into a single DAO in Spring - bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

Let's say I have the following Spring Mongo repositories. ObjectOne, ObjectTwo and ObjectThree represent documents stored in separate collections within the same database

```
public interface RepositoryOne extends MongoRepository<ObjectOne, String> {
}

public interface RepositoryTwo extends MongoRepository<ObjectTwo, String> {
}

public interface RepositoryThree extends MongoRepository<ObjectThree, String> {
}
```

And then a single DAO class

```
public class ExampleDAO {
    @Autowired
    private RepositoryOne repositoryOne;

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryTwo repositoryTwo;

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryThree repositoryThree;

    //Various methods performing operations with repositoryOne
    //Various methods performing operations with repositoryTwo
    //Various methods performing operations with repositoryThree
}
```

Is it considered bad practice to be autowiring multiple repositories into a single DAO like above? It feels like the class may be doing too much and ideally I should have a single repository to maintain single responsibility. If it is bad practice, would a separate DAO for each repository be the way to go, or is there a Spring magic way to create a single repository that I can use to call a more specific repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one will be able to tell whether your `ExampleDAO` is fine to use multiple repositories or not unless looking into the actual business logic.

However, your `ExampleDAO` class seems like acting as a business service (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550124/what-is-the-difference-between-dao-and-repository-patterns) for the subject of DAO vs Repository, they both actually different ways of implementing data access layers). In other words, you need to ensure that your `ExampleDAO` class handles/owns a single responsibility.

Also, the other important point is that it is a bad practice to use the field injection rather use the constructor injection. I suggest you go through [here](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) on this subject.

Comment: Thank you for the links, especially the constructor injection one.

Answer (score 4):

Its a bad practice to have multiple **unrelated** responsibilities for a single class. If they are related consider creating a 'service' class and autowire the repositories. And also the methods in service class can abstract the methods in repositories, for example:

```
class ExampleService {
    @Autowired
    private RepositoryOne repositoryOne;

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryTwo repositoryTwo;

    void saveEmployee(Employee e) {
        repositoryOne.save(e);
        repositoryTwo.update(e.getEmpId);
    }
}
```