# Repository vs. DAO (again)

Tags: spring, web-services, server, abstraction-layer

In general this back-story does not matter but just to explain the code below:

The server handles users and user groups. User groups are able to "discover" places - at this point in time these places are coming exclusively from the Google Places API.

---

### Current Implementation

---

Currently, I have a lot of `JpaRepository` objects, which I call *Repository*, in my Service Layer. I am stressing "*Repository*" because in my proposed solution below, they'd be downgraded to DAOs.

However, what I do not like in my current code, and also the reason for my question here, is the amount of repositories one can find in the `UserGroupService`.

```
@Service
public class UserGroupService {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(UserGroupService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserGroupRepository userGroupRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserGroupPlaceRepository userGroupPlaceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PlaceRepository placeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GooglePlaceRepository googlePlaceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GooglePlaces googlePlaces;

    public UserGroupService() {
    }

    @Transactional
    public void discoverPlaces(Long groupId) {

        final UserGroup userGroup = this.userGroupRepository.findById(groupId).orElse(null);

        if (userGroup == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("User group with id %s not found.", groupId));
        }

        List<PlacesSearchResult> allPlaces = this.googlePlaces.findPlaces(
                userGroup.getLatitude(),
                userGroup.getLongitude(),
                userGroup.getSearchRadius());

        allPlaces.forEach(googlePlaceResult -> {

            GooglePlace googlePlace = this.googlePlaceRepository.findByGooglePlaceId(googlePlaceResult.placeId);

            if (googlePlace != null) {
                return;
            }

            Place place = new Place();
            place.setLatitude(googlePlaceResult.geometry.location.lat);
            place.setLongitude(googlePlaceResult.geometry.location.lng);
            place.setPlaceType(Place.PlaceType.GOOGLE_PLACE);
            place.setName(googlePlaceResult.name);
            place.setVicinity(googlePlaceResult.vicinity);

            place = this.placeRepository.save(place);

            UserGroupPlace.UserGroupPlaceId userGroupPlaceId = new UserGroupPlace.UserGroupPlaceId();
            userGroupPlaceId.setUserGroup(userGroup);
            userGroupPlaceId.setPlace(place);

            UserGroupPlace userGroupPlace = new UserGroupPlace();
            userGroupPlace.setUserGroupPlaceId(userGroupPlaceId);

            this.userGroupPlaceRepository.save(userGroupPlace);

            googlePlace = new GooglePlace();
            googlePlace.setPlace(place);
            googlePlace.setGooglePlaceId(googlePlaceResult.placeId);

            this.googlePlaceRepository.save(googlePlace);
        });
    }
}
```

---

### A Solution That Does Not Work

---

What *could* make this code a lot simpler and had the potential to resolve this mess up there, would be `@Inheritance`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "place")
@Inheritance(strategy InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Place { /* .. */ }

@Entity
@Table(name = "google_place")
public class GooglePlace extends Place { /* .. */ }
```

However, this is not an option because then I cannot have a `PlaceRepository` which saves *just a place*. [Hibernate does not seem to like it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804053/psqlexception-the-column-name-clazz-was-not-found-in-this-resultset).

---

### My proposal

---

I think my confusion starts with the names that Spring is using. E.g. `JpaRepository` - I am not so sure if this is actually "the right" name. Because as far as I understood, these objects actually work like data access objects (DAOs). I think it should actually look something like this:

```
public interface PlaceDao extends JpaRepository<Place, Long> {
}

public interface GooglePlaceDao extends JpaRepository<Place, Long> {
}

@Repository
public class GooglePlaceRepository {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceDao placeDao;

    @Autowired
    private GooglePlaceDao googlePlaceDao;

    public List<GooglePlace> findByGroupId(Long groupId) {
    // ..
    }

    public void save(GooglePlace googlePlace) {
    // ..
    }

    public void saveAll(List<GooglePlace> googlePlaces) {
    // ..
    }
}

@Service
public class UserGroupService {

    @Autowired
    private GooglePlaceRepository googlePlaceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserGroupRepository userGroupRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void discoverPlaces(Long groupId) {

    final UserGroup userGroup = this.userGroupRepository.findById(groupId).orElse(null)
        .orElseThrow(throw new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("User group with id %s not found.", groupId)));


    List<PlacesSearchResult> fetched = this.googlePlaces.findPlaces(
            userGroup.getLatitude(),
            userGroup.getLongitude(),
            userGroup.getSearchRadius());

    // Either do the mapping here or let GooglePlaces return 
    // List<GooglePlace> instead of List<PlacesSearchResult>

    List<GooglePlace> places = fetched.stream().map(googlePlaceResult -> {
        GooglePlace googlePlace = this.googlePlaceRepository.findByGooglePlaceId(googlePlaceResult.placeId);

        if (googlePlace != null) {
            return googlePlace;
        }

        Place place = new Place();
        place.setLatitude(googlePlaceResult.geometry.location.lat);
        place.setLongitude(googlePlaceResult.geometry.location.lng);
        place.setPlaceType(Place.PlaceType.GOOGLE_PLACE);
        place.setName(googlePlaceResult.name);
        place.setVicinity(googlePlaceResult.vicinity);
        googlePlace = new GooglePlace();
        googlePlace.setPlace(place);
        googlePlace.setGooglePlaceId(googlePlaceResult.placeId);
        return googlePlace;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    this.googlePlaceRepository.saveAll(places);        

    // Add places to group..
    }

}
```

---

### Summary

---

I would like to know what I don't see. Am I fighting the framework, or does my data model not make sense and this is why I find myself struggling with this? Or am I still having issues on how the two patterns "Repository" and "DAO" are supposed to be used?

How would one implement this?

Comment: Better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Good question, shallow answers. Hope Code Review was a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are correct that there are too many repository dependencies in your service. Personally, I try to keep the number of `@Autowired` dependencies to a minimum and I try to use a repository only in one service and expose its higher level functionality via that service. At our company we call that data sovereignty (in German: *Datenhoheit*) and its purpose is to ensure that there is only one place in the application where those entities are modified.

From what I understand from your code I would introduce a `PlacesService` which has all the Dependencies to the `PlaceRepository`, `GooglePlaceRepository` and `GooglePlaces`. If you feel like *Service* is not the right name you could also call it the `PlacesDao`, mark it with a Spring `@Component` annotation and inject all the *Repositories*, which are by definition collections of things

```
@Component
public class PlacesDao {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceRepository placeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GooglePlaceRepository googlePlaceRepository;
```

This service/DAO could offer an API `findPlacesForGroup(userGroup)` and `createNewPlace(...)` and thus making your for Loop smaller and more elegant.

On a side note: you can merge your first four lines into just one. Java Optionals support a `orElseThrow()` method:

```
UserGroup userGroup = userGroupRepository.findById(groupId).orElseThrow(() -> 
     new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("User group with id %s not found.", groupId));
```

Comment: Hm. Well I agree, but I do not really like the naming "*service*" here - because at this point we are already in the Service-Layer. So from my point of view, this can only be a business object, right? The question here is how to abstract a business object which works with models (`Place`, `GooglePlace`) using repositories. The thing here is - I think what I am calling repository in my code (e.g. `placeRepository`) is not a repository but actually a DAO and that I am just confusing this because the annotation in Spring is called `@Reposiroty` and/or the interfaces are called `CrudRepository` ..

Comment: .. and so on. However, I am getting the feeling that each repository is actually just a DAO and that all these DAOs should actually life in a *actual* repository which is supposed to do the heavy lifting here.

Comment: I guess it depends on what code you move. If you move business logic I would call it a _service_, because that is where business logic belongs. Calling one service from an other is fine, imho. If you are only moving low level data operations, you could create a `PlaceAdapter` that wraps away all Repositories (I am deliberately not calling it a DAO). 
Here is a Stackoverflow Post on [Repository vs DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550124/what-is-the-difference-between-dao-and-repository-patterns)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already seen this post - and I've studied the answers as well. The problem is that they always talk about simple objects - in my opinion everything breaks as one would require object inheritance. I have updated my question and made things more clear hopefully.

Comment: I agree, most examples use very simple objects. Not sure, if inheritance is the solution. From how I understand your use case, it looks more like your business object is compound of several smaller entities. Similar in a way where one would store a binary file in an object storage and at the same time its meta data in a DB. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hm, here is the thing a DAO is considered closer to the database than a repository (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550228/826983)) - hence my question particularly aims at whether it would make sense to call my repositories `PlaceDao extends `JpaRepository` - there's a naming conflict. I am looking for a much more detailed explanation. I want - finally - once and for all - have an idea how these abstraction layers are actually supposed to work together. The major problem imho is that there is a ton of simple examples out there but no corner cases where you'd need inheritance etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the foreach does not look like a good approach to me. You're doing way to much for just a single responsibility of a function. I would refactor this to a standart for loop.

```
        Place place = new Place();
        place.setLatitude(googlePlaceResult.geometry.location.lat);
        place.setLongitude(googlePlaceResult.geometry.location.lng);
        place.setPlaceType(Place.PlaceType.GOOGLE_PLACE);
        place.setName(googlePlaceResult.name);
        place.setVicinity(googlePlaceResult.vicinity);

        place = this.placeRepository.save(place);
```

This part can easily be a method in a service.

```
        UserGroupPlace.UserGroupPlaceId userGroupPlaceId = new 
        UserGroupPlace.UserGroupPlaceId();
        userGroupPlaceId.setUserGroup(userGroup);
        userGroupPlaceId.setPlace(place);

        UserGroupPlace userGroupPlace = new UserGroupPlace();
        userGroupPlace.setUserGroupPlaceId(userGroupPlaceId);

        this.userGroupPlaceRepository.save(userGroupPlace);
```

That part as well.

```
        googlePlace = new GooglePlace();
        googlePlace.setPlace(place);
        googlePlace.setGooglePlaceId(googlePlaceResult.placeId);

        this.googlePlaceRepository.save(googlePlace);
```

And this part: I don't understand why your doing this. You could just update the googlePlace instance you loaded from the repo. Hibernate/Transactions are doing the rest for you.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. So the thing is this: I have different types of places (another is `CUSTOM_PLACE` (CP)). A `UserGroupPlace` therefore can display a CP and `GOOGLE_PLACE` (GP). A GP however takes additional information (`placeId`) which means I have to write a new `Place`, `UserGroupPlace` and a `GooglePlace`. What I *could* do is create a `UserGroupGooglePlaceDao` which wraps the functionality and only deals with this type of place by ensuring that such a place gets stored in the database correctly. However, I'd also need a `UserGroupCustomPlaceDao` for this particular type.

Comment: At this point I am not sure if this is really the way to go. To have a `*Dao` for every type of entity I want to store in the database. Another way would be to de-normalize my tables in the database and allow nullable values - but would that be "cleaner"?

Comment: To be honest this is getting really detailed.  It can be reasonable to hold nullable fields in combination with a dtype. For example when the usage of the child classes does not change per child class and you can work only on the parent class. Otherwise I would not hold nullable fields.